# How to delete a xml file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, delete-file, xmlwriter

I'm trying to delete my XML file and it's not working. I don't get an error so I don't know what the problem is.  Here is my code.

```
    Dim filePath As String = "\\server02\file$\rss\alert-special-reports2.xml" 
      If Not New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Exists Then 
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath) 
      End If
```

Comment: You wrote "if **not** exist then delete it". It won't be executed even supposing ASP.NET user has enough privileges to delete the file.

Comment: 0 out of 8 accepted? Please accept some answers!

Comment: I just found out from our server admin that it is a permission issue on this particular server.  Our development server is working fine so I used the same code.  It works on serverDev but not serverStaging.  I was told initially that both servers had the same rights, not true.  That's our IT Help Desk for you, I think they are reading from a script. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The C# code for this would be like this(and Similar for VB):

```
  string filePath = "\\server02\file$\rss\alert-special-reports2.xml";
  File.Delete(filePath);
```

The thing to be noted here is that you **dont need any IF EXISTS** thing here. It would automatically delete the file if it exists and if it doesn't, it **wont throw any exception**.